# Xaml TextBox not behaving

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am trying to create UI from XAML at runtime, with something like

```
private void Application_Startup (object esender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  this.RootVisual = (UIElement)(XmlReader.Load(e.InitParams["Xaml"])
```

If I feed it this XAML:

```
<Canvas
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
  xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls">

<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Width="120" Margin="8" Text="Edit Me" />
  <CheckBox Margin="8">Normal</CheckBox>
  <ComboBox Margin="8" Width="120" SelectedIndex="1">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="First Normal Item" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Second Normal Item" />
  </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

then the check box and list behave as expected, but my TextBox does not respond to typing, it stays with its initial value.
The really weird (to me) part is that if I put a handler for KeyDown on to the RootVisual, and in there display a message box, it works. If I have an empty handler or no handler it doesn't.

Do I need to set up some explicit handling for some events? If so, which ones, and how do I handle them?

Upadate: as suggested, I tried putting the dynamic markup into the MainPage of a new app, like this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dynamic = XamlReader.Load(xaml);
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dynamic as UIElement);
    }
```

where `xaml` is a string literal containing the content as above, and everything else is just how VS2010 wizard left it. That works. But I can't see what the effective difference is.

Update update: that's a red herring; the difference is the environment. It works in VS, but not in the Silverlight ActiveX control that I am using in the real app.

Comment: oops, yes I do. And the parentheses line up in the real code too :)

Comment: As a side note: `var dynamic = XamlReader.Load(xaml);` had me baffled for a couple of seconds... please choose your variable names carefully.

Comment: I hadn't realised that was a reserved word. At least I learned one thing today.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, just confusing: assigning the result of a method that returns an object created by paring a string, to a variable named dynamic which type is determined by the compiler using var....

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the root namespace on your root element?

```
      <param name="initParams" value="xaml=&lt;TextBox xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' Text='hi'/&gt;" />
```

Just a shot in the dark here, but have you tried adding the dynamically created content as the child of a static "MainPage.xaml" Grid instead of as RootVisual?

Comment: Regarding the namespaces, yes, I've attached an example.

Comment: Regarding the MainPage.xaml, yes that seems to work, as noted above. But what's the difference? Argh!

Comment: Just tried creating a new UserControl as RootVisual, and setting its Content to the dynamic content. No change. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check for `IsEnabled="True"` property in your main XAML file, if it is set to `false` then controls will not be editable.